# Can I run Concerto?

Tags: operating-systems

I would like to set up the Raspberry Pi as a simple box that runs [Concerto](http://www.concerto-signage.org/)  exclusively. That way I can use an older TV as a screen.

Are there any tips or better solutions out there that I don't know of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/concerto-digital-signage/VbEZDhGWKZc/IUtyP2zFA7MJ) on the Concerto Google Group, it is very possible.

**EDIT:**
For those that are looking for the summarized steps, here they are:

Start with a Stock Install of Raspbian - at setup, choose to expand the disk to full sd card, and boot into window manager.

after Raspbian is up and running:

1.) Make the mouse pointer disappear:

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
```

2.) Set up the LXDE X Window to automatic start the web browser midori with your web page.

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
@midori -e Fullscreen -a http://yoursignserver/screen/?mac=yourmacaddress
```

3.) Switch off the automatic screen blanking.

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Enable in the category 'SeatDefaults' the xserver-command like following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms
```

Reboot and you should have a functioning Screen.

Comment: Do you mind summarizing the post a little here? It takes a bit more effort to read the link and there may be some confusion over which bit is intended to be read.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually part of that discussion. I was hoping to see if anyone not part of the google group had figured it out. (this was before someone posted a solution)

Comment: I just made a [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/109112143853981019166/posts/AZU1xsQ9Yvw) with a picture of one of the screens I spent this afternoon working on.

I started with a default Raspbian image, installed the chromium-browser package from the repository, configured Chromium to load Concerto on boot, and followed [these instructions](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=18200) to disable screen blanking.

I [infrequently blog](http://blog.kenleycheung.com) about my exploits in Concerto-land and once I get this finished, I'll blog about the experience.

Comment: @bearbin I added the steps for you. Sorry I hadn't checked back on this question in so long.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can!

Remember, the client is just a stripped down debian install running firefox to access the concerto bakend.  So all you really need to do is run a fullscreen firefox instance!  The best bet would be to set up a bash script that runs on boot to automatically start firefox in fullscreen mode and point it at your concerto server.

The custom concerto client iso that is supplied will not work because it is only designed for the x86 architecture.  Also running RPI software on the Rpi?  It's like a match made in heaven!

Comment: `set up a bash script that runs on boot`. This exists already. It's called `.xinitrc`.

Answer (score 1):

replace midori by iceweasel(firefox)
there is some trouble with graphic css in epiphany and midori

Install iceweasel

> sudo apt-get install iceweasel

Add iceweasel in autostart script

> sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

add

> @iceweasel

Open iceweasel and set http://yourconcertoserver/frontend (concerto server v2) as default page and load fullscreen in options

Answer (score 0):

I still have Concerto v1 running on an old Raspberry Pi as both server and (chromium based) front-end. It's very limited, can only show static images with no complex transitions, but a complete standalone system that's been very reliable. The only failures have been when the SD card has filled up!

I wouldn't recommend it ... as that version of Concerto was only compiled for the old RPi, but have got a lot of mileage out of it.